# 400 Bad Request from SharePoint Online is received in CSOM call when add character '#'

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, flurl

I have a problem with tested c# code to fetch the Files and folder details from SPO Teamsite which is working very fine otherwise but not when SPO repository names a folder with '#'. *Example: ABC#123 or My#Folder*.

We are using Flur to make the call to SharePoint Online and it returns us Bad request - 400 exception in REST call. I have checked that it is not caused by encoding issue and **folderName** is having no encodes of '#'. It has names in Flur Url as on SharePoint repository. Below is the sample REST URL followed by Flur call sample and at the end we capture the response in our exception block with Bad Request to said Url.

[https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/myteamsite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/myteamsite/MyFolder/A#3')/?$expand=Folders/ListItemAllFields,Files/ListItemAllFields](https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/myteamsite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(%27/sites/myteamsite/MyFolder/A#3%27)/?$expand=Folders/ListItemAllFields,Files/ListItemAllFields)

```
await myUrl
   .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
   .WithHeader("Authorization", myAuthX)
   .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose")
   .WithHeader("Connection", "close")
   .GetAsync();
```

Comment: That's a bad URL to begin with. `#` is used for the [fragment part of a URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment), just as `://` is used for the scheme and `:` for the port. Where did this URL come from? What's the actual folder name? What's its actual URL?

Comment: Why aren't you using SharePoint's own client API? In any case, the URL of a file in a document library actually matches the directory structure. You can right-click on a file and inspect its URL.